# jqueryUI draggable custom helper goes behind relatively positioned div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am fighting with a drag-and-drop event scheduling app. I have some relatively positioned blocks, and the custom helper for my draggable goes behind them. I have tried various fixes such as adjusting the z-indices of the different blocks, using the draggable "stack" option, etc.  But the only thing that seems to work is removing "position: relative" from the relative blocks, which isn't really an option.

HTML:

```
<div id="container-one">
    <div class="draggable" id="drag-block"></div>

</div>

<div id="container-two">
    <div class="static-block" id="block-one"></div>
    <div class="static-block" id="block-two"></div>
    <div class="static-block" id="block-three"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        cursorAt: { bottom: 0, left: 20 },
        helper: function( event ) 
        {
            return $( "<div class='drag-helper'><h2><i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i></h2></div>" );
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#container-one {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#drag-block {
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;

}

#container-two {
    background-color: green;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.static-block {
    height: 80px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

#block-one {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 40px;
}

#block-two {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left: 70px;
}

#block-three {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    left: 140px;
}

.drag-helper {
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #363636;
}

p {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

Any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/voveson/08L32rye/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple fix using z-index:

```
.drag-helper {
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #363636;
    z-index: 10; // <---
}
```

Working fine for me!

http://jsfiddle.net/myawfhx6/1/

Comment: So weird... I could've sworn I'd tried that.  In any case, my jsFiddle must not be close enough to my actual code, because the simple fix isn't working for me there.